# difference of compiler between macOS and linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am now learning c language, and my school put all assignments on myth, every time we have to log in by ssh and execute command remotely.
Thus I want to download the files and execute them on my own macbook. However when I use make command to compile the files, I got errors and warnings such as :

```
gcc -g -O0 -std=gnu99 -Wall $warnflags -m32   -c -I. vectest.c -o vectest.o
warning: unknown warning option '-Wlogical-op'; did you mean '-Wlong-long'?

vectest.c:10:10: fatal error: 'error.h' file not found
#include <error.h>”
```

I googled these problems but could not find a satisfactory answer. can anyone help me solve this ? or I have to use a linux machine instead?

Comment: There's no such standard header `<error.h>`. If you want to be able to port between platforms then you should either use only standard features or [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation).

Comment: Also note that depending on your setup, on Mac OSX the `gcc` command may simply be an alias for `clang`, meaning you don't actually use GCC on OSX.

Comment: yep. thanks for reminding!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I use Makefile, in which I use "CC = gcc"  so does mac use gcc or still use clang?

Comment: "Alias" might have been the wrong term, it's most likely a symbolic link. So no matter where it's called from the link will resolve to the Clang compiler. Note that it only happens if you haven't actually manually installed GCC.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed; compilers for various platforms (even if it's the "same" compiler, such as GCC) may have different flags and behaviors. You may be able to get it to work - you could remove the `-Wlogical-op` flag from `$warnflags` in your `Makefile`, but if the `error.h` file is a system-supplied header file, you're probably in trouble. Therefore, I suggest that you download e.g. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and run Linux on it.

Comment: Installing a VM just to fix a simple build problem seems a bit drastic - it should be easy enough to fix the issue, and if not then there are easier workarounds, such as installing a generic gcc from e.g. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: @PaulR: The OP seems to be taking a course in which the exercises provide a ready-made development environment. "Fixing" these problems might get increasingly hard as the complexity of the exercises increase (and it will distract from the main objective of the course, which is presumably to learn C, not to dabble with the flags of the compiler), and worse, it might render her homework ungradeable because the staff presumably use Linux.

Comment: Fair point - although using gcc from Homebrew or MacPorts would probably still be a lot easier for a noob than setting up a Linux VM.

Answer (score 1):

See [`error(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/error) for what this header provides. It's not specific to linux but to the *GNU C library*. What you COULD do is provide your own minimal implementation of these functions and write your own `error.h`.

You could even `#define' them to do nothing at all, but then you will probably lose some error reporting in the existing code. Maybe you could try to find a teacher understanding the problem and discuss the issue ... it's probably better to learn *standard C* not using any platform-specific extensions.